# Monotonic sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following sequence

$a_n$ $=$ $(1-\frac{1}{2})*(1-\frac{1}{4})*...*(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$

I have to prove if it converges or not, so I started with checking if it is monotonic or not.
For that I constructed the $a_{n+1}$ sequence such as:

$a_{n+1}$ $=$ $(1-\frac{1}{4})*(1-\frac{1}{8})*...*(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$

Then I divided $a_n$ by $a_{n+1}$ which will leave first element of $a_n$ and the last element of $a_{n+1}$, which equals

$\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}$

After some simplifications I have got

$\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{2^n}}$

I concluded that it is smaller than 1, as denominator is more than 1, which means $a_n$ $\leq$ $a_{n+1}$, which implies that sequence is increasing, however when I calculate some small values for $n$

n=1, $a_n$ = 0.5;

n=2, $a_n$ = 0.375 and so on

I can clearly see that sequence is in fact decreasing.

Can someone please help me find my mistake?

Comment: What you call $a_{n+1}$ isn't.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $a_{n+1}=(1-\frac12)\cdots(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n= (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})...(1-\frac{1}{2^n})$ then $a_{n+1} = (1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{4})...(1-\frac{1}{2^n})(1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}})$.

Comment: This shows that it converges. This does not show that it converges to a positive value, which is, in my opinion, the more interesting result.

Answer (score 0):

You want
$(1-\frac{1}{2})*(1-\frac{1}{4})*...*(1-\frac{1}{2^n})
$.

More generally, 
let
$a_n
=\prod_{k=1}^n (1-a^k)
$,
where
$0 < a < 1$.
Your case is
$a = \frac12$.

Then
$\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (1-a^k)}{\prod_{k=1}^n (1-a^k)}
=1-a^{n+1}
\lt 1
$,
so the sequence is decreasing.

Therefore it has a limit,
which may be zero.

To see if the limit is
greater than zero,
my first inclination
is to use
$\ln(1-x)
\gt -x-x^2
$
for
$0 < x < 0.68380$
(approximately,
according to Wolfy).

Therefore,
if
$0 < a < 0.68380$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(a_n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1-a^k)\\
&\gt\sum_{k=1}^n (-a^k-a^{2k})\\
&=-\sum_{k=1}^n (a^k+a^{2k})\\
&\gt-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a^k+a^{2k})\\
&=-\dfrac{a}{1-a}-\dfrac{a^2}{1-a^2}\\
&=-\dfrac{a(1+a)+a^2}{1-a^2}\\
&=-\dfrac{a(1+2a)}{1-a^2}\\
\end{array}
$

If $a = \frac12$,
$\ln(a_n)
\gt -\dfrac{\frac12(1+1)}{1-\frac12^2}
=-\frac43
$,
so
$a_n
\gt e^{-\frac43}
\gt 0.263
$,
so the limit is positive.